# Wouldn't Han Solo have been alive when the Jedi were eliminated?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, jedi, han-solo

I was watching *The Force Awakens* and there is a line uttered by Han Solo in the film in regards to Rey's comment regarding the Jedi.  She has been on Jakku for a long time and she is very young, so it makes sense that she is out of the loop when it comes to the time line thirty years before.  But Han says, when Rey says, "The Jedi were real!",

> Han:  "I used to wonder about that myself.  Thought it was a bunch of mumbo jumbo..."

And we know that he was not really a believer in the Force.  But how could he not know that the Jedi were real.  He was 10 at the time of Revenge of the Sith and he must have grown up with the Old Republic so he must have heard stories of the Jedi "Betrayal" of the Republic once the Empire took over and must have heard about the Jedi being wiped out.  Also, as Chewbacca knew Yoda, how would he not believe that they were real?  This seems far fetched...

Comment: Martha's answer is especially useful in this context. In a universe of several trillion individuals, there were only 10,000-ish Jedi. That means the average person has a 1-in-a-billion chance of ever having *met* a Jedi, let alone seeing one in action.

Comment: @Richard But I thought Anakin Skywalker was as famous as a rock star is now? He was a huge war hero wasn't he?

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - Yes, in the core worlds of the Old Republic, in those places that had regular Holonet access. Don't forget though that Han tends to hang around the outer edges of Hutt Space, making only the occasional trip into the Republic to pick up drug shipments. It's not like he was a mad Jedi fanboy to begin with. He seems to mostly think it's a hoax or a hokey old religion.

Comment: @Richard Yep. I forgot Han likes  to stick to the outer-rim jobs.

Comment: @Richard And yet Han himself had met no less than two (three if you count Vader) and seen them in action. He definitely thinks it's a lot of mumbo-jumbo this whole Force thing, but he _knows_ from first-hand experience that the Jedi were a real thing. And don't forget that even Luke, who was younger than Han and had spent his entire life on Tatooine, seemed to know (in general terms) what the Jedi were.

Comment: considering some people dont believe in moon landings, its not hard to think some percentage of galaxy might not believe in jedi